# How to make a popup window like facebook popup photo?

Tags: jquery, facebook, colorbox

like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE8et.jpg

the right side is content (fixed width), the left side is photo, like full screen.

I tried to use colorbox, but failed.

the failed link: http://www.novalab.com.hk/demo/homeda/photos

there has scroll  :(

any open sources like facebook that one?

thanks!

Comment: open source? `CTRL + U` on chrome? :o

Comment: @_@ tried, seems not easy to copy...

Comment: Of course I'm not saying you should copy, but at least you can see how they get it done and apply it to your requirement? :o